# Delay ajax request for 3 seconds before processing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax script to send data. I want to display `.coin-flip` for 3 seconds before the data is sent/processed. Once this 3 seconds are over the data will be sent to flip-process.php normally and then the return result will be displayed on success. But currently its so fast that I just can see the coin flipping here (the animation I want to display). Therefore, I want a delay of 3 seconds before processing the ajax request. How can I do so?

Here is my ajax script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var dataString = {
            flip: $("#flip").val(),
            amount: $("#amount").val(),
        };
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "flip-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
      beforeSend: function(){
                $("#coins").hide();
                $(".coin-flip").show();
      },
            success: function(html){
                $(".message").html(html).fadeIn();
                    $("#coins").show();
                    $(".coin-flip").hide();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Use setTimeout method for it
setTimeout(function(){//action stuff },3000);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easist option would be to use a timeout in your success function, rather than delay the actual request:

```
success: function(html){
    setTimeout(function(){

        $(".message").html(html).fadeIn();
        $("#coins").show();
        $(".coin-flip").hide();

    },3000);
}
```

Comment: perfect solution... :D

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
setTimeout(function(){ callAjax(); }, 3000);

function callAjax(){
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "flip-process.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: true,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#coins").hide();
            $(".coin-flip").show();
        },
        success: function(html){
            $(".message").html(html).fadeIn();
                $("#coins").show();
                $(".coin-flip").hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use setTimeout inside your `beforeSend` block.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var dataString = {
            flip: $("#flip").val(),
            amount: $("#amount").val(),
        };
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "flip-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
            success: function(html){
                setTimeout(function(){

                    $(".message").html(html).fadeIn();
                    $("#coins").show();
                    $(".coin-flip").hide();

                },3000);
             }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap the ajax call in timeout

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                var dataString = {
                    flip: $("#flip").val(),
                    amount: $("#amount").val(),
                };
                var processing=false;


            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "flip-process.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: true,
              beforeSend: function(){
                        $("#coins").hide();
                        $(".coin-flip").show();
              },
                    success: function(html){
                        $(".message").html(html).fadeIn();
                            $("#coins").show();
                            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                            if (!processing)
                           {
                            processing=true;
                            $(".coin-flip").hide();
                            }
                    }, 2000}
                });

);
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: this hides the entire thing for three seconds.. I want to show the `.coin-flip` inside the `beforeSend` to be displayed for 3 seconds and then hide and show the result eventually..